# How to get raw binary data from flask request, not unicode escaped

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get the raw binary data recieved by flask printed to the console.  I am using

```
print(request.get_data(), file=sys.stdout)
```

But what I get is some unicode escaped output.  Here is the first part of that:

```
b'------WebKitFormBoundary3lOc6VBmgP6uwjTD\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test_image.png"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xf4x\xd4\xfa\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x00\x00\x0b\x13\x01\x00\x9a\x9c\x18\x00\x00 \x00IDATx\x9c\xed\xdd\x07\x98\x15\xd5\xdd\xc7\xf1\xc5\x18\xd8\xb9wY@\x89h\xec&j4\x89\x89\xd1hbT4\xd1\x88JT\xd8\x99\xbb4\xc1\x121\x1a51\x16
```

How can I get the raw binary data that was uploaded without unicode escapes?

Answer (score 2):

What you get is form data and I think you want to receive the uploaded file.
Try [`request.files`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.files) and you will get a file-like object of type [`FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage). From this you can read the content of the file with `read()`.

```
file = request.files['file']
data = file.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets rid of the headers and boundaries, which is nice, but the file is still unicode escaped.

Comment: What makes you think it's unicode? I think it should be a [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects).

Comment: Because its all escaped text.  Example: \x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00

Comment: It is an ASCII representation of binary data. It starts with the header of a PNG file. (8 bytes: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10 -> b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n') [PNG-Format](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) What are you working towards?

Comment: For clarity: When outputting to the console, numbers that cannot be represented as characters are output in hexadecimal. PNG format conforms to Big Endian encoding (Network Byte Order).

Comment: very true, if you're printing to console, data might or will get reformatted. print output is basically the "visual interpretation" of whatever you're printing. check it with isinstance() what type it actually is.